# Drag multiple elements with jquery.event.drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop

I want to drag multiple elements with the jQuery plugin [jquery.event.drag](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag)

Here is a [fiddle of the original demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/8JP72/1/) :

Here is the link to the [original demo](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/demo/multi) :

On the demo, the user clicks on squares he wants to select and drag them.

But i want to do something simplest : Just click on the square "1" and move all the squares.

I've tried different things and the result is not good, see this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/gVFCL/2/

Can you help me to that that ?

HTML code :

```
<div class="drag" style="left:20px;"></div>
<div class="drag" style="left:100px;"></div>
<div class="drag" style="left:180px;"></div>
```

CSS code

```
.drag {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #89B;
    background: #BCE;
    height: 58px;
    width: 58px;
    cursor: move;
    top: 120px;
}
.selected {
    background-color: #ECB;
    border-color: #B98;
    }
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.drag')
        .click(function(){
            $( this ).toggleClass("selected");
        })
        .drag("init",function(){
            if ( $( this ).is('.selected') )
                return $('.selected');
        })
        .drag(function( ev, dd ){
            $( this ).css({
                top: dd.offsetY,
                left: dd.offsetX
            });
        });
});
```

EDIT
The link given in Rajagopal's answer is ok.
I've also found this plugin MultiDraggable which is really easy to use : https://github.com/someshwara/MultiDraggable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do something like this,

```
$('.drag').drag("init", function(ev, dd) {
    if (this.id == "test") {
        return $(".drag").addClass("selected");
    }
}).drag(function(ev, dd) {
    if (ev.target.id == "test") {
        $(this).css({
            top: dd.offsetY,
            left: dd.offsetX
        });
    }
});​
```

Here is the working [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ubEqb/). Hope, this one will help you.

**EDIT:**

You can simply use jquery-ui draggable plugin for this case. Take a look at this http://jqfaq.com/how-to-drag-the-multiple-elements-with-jquery-ui-draggable/. Hoep, this one will help you!

Comment: Thanks, it's what i want to do. It's strange but the fiddle works fine, but when i use this code in my project, the drag of my elements is horribly laggy. I'll check my code. The only difference is that i try to drag more complexes divs (with images, paragraph). Maybe the plugin doesn't support that.

Comment: Thanks. I've also found this plugin which is really easy to use : https://github.com/someshwara/MultiDraggable

Comment: Yeah these elements are still very laggy in the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('.drag').drag("init", function() {
        if ($(this).is('#test')){
            return $('.selected');
        }
    }).drag(function(ev, dd) {
        $( this ).css({
                top: dd.offsetY,
                left: dd.offsetX
            });
    });
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/gVFCL/3/

Comment: Thank you for creating this fiddle. It's nice but i want to do something slightly different. I want square 2 and square 3 to be dragged only if square 1 is dragged (in the fiddle we can drag square 2 and square 3 by selecting square 2 and square 3).

Answer (score 2):

My code upgrade multi drag and multi select:

http://jsfiddle.net/F4AwY/

```
$('.drag').drag("init", function() {
  return $('.selected');
}).drag(function(ev, dd) {
    $( this ).css({
       top: dd.offsetY,
       left: dd.offsetX
    });
});

$('div[class*="drag"]').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the original jsfiddle change

```
.click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    })
```

to

```
.click(function(){
        $('.drag').toggleClass("selected");
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's nice but i want to do something slightly different. I want square 2 and square 3 to be dragged only if square 1 is dragged (in your code, we can select all the squares).