# how to make an overlay of google maps stand on top of the zoom bar

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3

So here is how I create an overlay (the standart way). Problem is, when I drag the map around, the overlay gets behind the zoom bar and other controls. I want those controls to go behind the overlay. I tried changing the z-index of the overlay but that doesn't work because parents of the overlay have low z-index. If I change z-index of the parents, the controls get hidden by the whole map. So the reason that changing z-index doesn't work is because overlay and zoom bar for example are in 2 different divs which themselves have z-index.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map {
            width: 600px;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        TestOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
        /** @constructor */
        function TestOverlay(map) {
            this.setMap(map);
        }

        /**
         * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
         * added to the map.
         */
        TestOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = "I want the zoombar to go behind me.";
            div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            div.style.position = "relative";
            div.style.fontSize = "20px";
            // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
            var panes = this.getPanes();
            panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
        };

        TestOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
        };

        // The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
        // we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
        TestOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
        };
        function init() {
            var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-35.397, 150.644);
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: mapCenter
            });
            new TestOverlay(map);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

As you can see. There is an overlay and thats about it, the rest comes from google maps api.
Thanks in advance.

So, in the end, very hacky and ugly but here's how I've done it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #map {
                width: 600px;
                height: 500px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            var ol;
            TestOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
            /** @constructor */
            function TestOverlay(map) {
                this.setMap(map);
            }

            /**
             * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
             * added to the map.
             */
            TestOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.id = "dummy";
                // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
                var panes = this.getPanes();
                panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);
            };

            TestOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
            };

            // The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
            // we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
            TestOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
            };
            function init() {
                var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-35.397, 150.644);
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: mapCenter
                });
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.id = "overlay";
                    div.className = "gmnoprint";
                    div.innerHTML = "Yes, the controls go behind me ;)";
                    div.style = "background-color:white;z-index:100000000000;position:absolute";
                    $(".gm-style").append(div);
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function() {

                    $("#overlay").css("left", $("#dummy").parent().parent().parent().css("left"))
                    $("#overlay").css("top", $("#dummy").parent().parent().parent().css("top"))
                });
                ol = new TestOverlay(map);
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Idea is that the overlay is on same level as the controls and there is a dummy overlay where the overlays are supposed to be. When drag event is fired, I get the coordinates of the dummy div, and put it in my overlay div. Thats about it :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand there are 6 layers to custom overlays these are as follows

1. mapPane
2. overlayLayer
3. overlayShadow
4. overlayImage
5. floatShadow
6. overlayMouseTarget
7. floatPane

Unfortunately they never designed it to allow overlays on top of the controls as in some cases this would make the map useless.

If you have not already, take a look at the developers website covering custom overlays. Who knows there may be a work around no one has found yet.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays#hide_show

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did take a look there and tried adding to all 7 panels. When I was inspecting with firebug, structure of the html of the google maps, I found that layer (div) of the overlay and its parent layer where the map itself with image is, gets updated when you drag the map around. However, the layer where the controls are, doesn't get updated when you drag the map around and putting overlay in same div with controls won't work either. By updated I mean, position properties get changed. So I can put something OVER the controls but it won't move around when the map is dragged.

Comment: In that case the only solution that I can think of that may work is having an overlay generated independently to the map in its own containing div. It would need to be above all other layers and be locked to a cordite within the the independent div. At that point implement some jQuery scripts that allow content to be dragged around the div. 

All of that is sadly a little out of my league but I know you can drag multiple instances at once as is outlined in this stack overflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055639/drag-multiple-elements-with-jquery-event-drag-javascript-jquery

Comment: I probably will add it in same div as controls are, and then catch events when map position is changed, and change the position of the overlay also, so it will work but its not very elegent. Will post solution if I manage to solve it.

Comment: Look forward to hearing the solution if you find it. Good luck!